# How to implementing callback using template functors in C++

Tags: c++, callback

Can you please explain me how can I implement callback function using template functors in C++.

I have read following article on this topic by Rich Hickey, but could not understand how can I use it   in my application.

http://www.tutok.sk/fastgl/callback.html

I have basic knowledge of functors and templates, and have already used it in my application.

Comment: Note that the article is from 1994. C++ evolved a lot since then.

Comment: A lot of [the standard algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) takes a "callback" as an argument. You could look at how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
void hello()
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

template <typename CB>
void func_with_cb(CB cb, int i)
{
    cb(i);
}

int main()
{
    func_with_cb([](int i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        hello();
    }, 5);
}
```

We use a template in our function to allow any arbitrary callback without knowing the typename beforehand (the compiler will still check all is well), and then pass the callback in using a lambda. We can also call named functions (such as `hello`) from within the anonymous lambda function

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [@Madden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303988/how-to-implementing-callback-using-template-functors-in-c/57304724#57304724) answers the question that was asked. This one is only a complement.

---

I don't know what exactly are your needs but I think you better have to use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of templates. It will allow you to give any callable target as arguments whether it is a function, a lambda, a functor, a bind expression, ... The only requirement is that it must be callable.

I hope it can help.